# PineGrow a good HTML editor?

Tags: html, css, text-editor

I'm a front-end developer and have been using Adobe Dreamweaver for years. But it just has so many weird glitches that never seem to get fixed, and they drive me crazy. Now I'm getting into CSS Grids, and Dreamweaver flags any "fr" units as errors, so I think I'm ready to try something else.

A colleague introduced me to PineGrow, which supports visual representations of CSS Grids within the app. It looks pretty cool, but as someone who writes their own code from scratch, I'm wondering if this type of visual layout app would be more cumbersome than helpful to someone who knows HTML and CSS well?

Does anyone have a strong opinion of PineGrow? Any other HTML editors you'd care to recommend?

Comment: Most WYSAWYG ("What You See Approximates What You Get" - inherent limitations in HTML rendering) HTML/CSS editors that I am aware of have a way of viewing and directly editing the HTML/CSS source. I use the last version of FrontPage, and routinely use it in WYSAWYG mode for most of the layout/content insertion, but where I know the code generated is poor, I'll then go into source-editing mode and fix/tweak those infelicities.

Comment: Please note that this site is about recommending software that meets specific requirements – not the other way around. For details, see [Are “Can I use X for Y” questions on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2816/185) Please **[edit]** your question in a way reflecting that, including your OS preferences and price margin. For guidance, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)